# Реализация словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, dict, передача-параметров

Существует словарь с аргументами, которые нужно указать для отправки запроса к API.

Он подается в формате:

```
{'param_name': 'value'}
```

Но дело в том, что мне нужно указывать эти аргументы при отправке запроса в виде:

```
https://url?method_name/&param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Вопрос состоит в том, как можно словарь распаковать в виде `&item=key`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь инструментом, созданным именно для этих целей - [urllib.parse.urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode):

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

data = {'param1': 'val1', 'param2': 'string with spaces'}

urlencode(data)
# 'param1=val1&param2=string+with+spaces'
```

PS `urllib.parse.urlencode()` - сам позаботится о правильном преобразовании и экранировании необходимых символов так, чтобы получился валидный URL.

Answer (score 2):

Какая библиотека используется для отправки запросов к API? Поскольку в [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) уже все готово и вам даже делать ничего не надо

```py
import requests

params = {'param_name': 'value',
        'param_name1': 'value1'}
url = "https://example.com/v1/method/"

response = request.get(url, params=params)
```

и вот такой вот запрос распакуется вот так

```py
https://example.com/v1/method/?param_name=value&param_name1=value1
```

Документацию можно глянуть [здесь](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

```
string = ''
for key, val in d.items():
    string += f'&{key}={val}'
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]